# Remove white spacings from shell command

Tags: shell, batch-file, certutil

I am developing a shell script that executes a command a returns a checksum string. This string is has each hexa separated with white spaces, something that I would like to remove and have, for example, 4AA512, instead of 4A A5 12 as command output but I am not able to find a solution that works. Here the script:

```
for /f  "delims=" %%f in ('dir %~dp0*.zip /b') do (
    echo %%~f:
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('certUtil -hashfile "%~dp0%%~f" SHA512 ^| find /i /v "SHA512" ^| find /i /v "certUtil"^') do (
          echo %%a:' '=''%
        )

    set /a counter += 1
    echo.
 )
```

Anyone has a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer, so it is more visible to future visitors?

Comment: `set "checksum=%~1"` (note: no second `%`) to remove any surrounding quotes (no need for `set checksum=%checksum:"=%`). And yes, please don't put a solution into the question. Make it an answer instead (and accept it).

Comment: Take a look at this script on [DosTips.com](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7592)

Comment: Finally got a solution:

    for /f  "delims=" %%f in ('dir %~dp0*.zip /b') do (
     echo %%~f:
     for /f "delims=" %%a in ('certUtil -hashfile "%~dp0%%~f" SHA512 ^| find /i /v "SHA512" ^| find /i /v "certUtil"^') do (call :ShowChecksum "%%a")
     set /a counter += 1
 
     echo.
    )

    echo %counter% files(s) found.
    pause
    exit

    :ShowChecksum
    set checksum=%1%
    set checksum=%checksum: =%
    set checksum=%checksum:"=%
    echo %checksum%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(answer moved from question/comment to - well - an answer)*

Finally got a solution:

```
set counter=0
for /f  "delims=" %%f in ('dir %~dp0*.zip /b') do (
    echo %%~f:
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('certUtil -hashfile "%~dp0%%~f" SHA512 ^| find /i /v "SHA512" ^| find /i /v "certUtil"^') do (call :ShowChecksum "%%a")
    set /a counter += 1
    echo.
)

echo %counter% files(s) found.
pause
exit

:ShowChecksum
set "checksum=%~1"
set "checksum=%checksum: =%"
echo %checksum%
```